# How to use Autocomplete inside Popover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, antd

As the question implies, I wanted to use the Autocomplete component inside of the content of a Popover component. The problem is that when I click one of the items shown by the Autocomplete component, the Popover closes, when I wanted for it to stay opened (it appears that it recognizes the click in the Autocomplete list as outside of the Popover). Is there a simple way to do that? I'm using something like the code below.

```
const content = (
  <Form onSubmit={this.doSomething}>
    <FormItem>
      <Autocomplete />
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem>
      <Button htmlType="submit">
        Do It
      </Button>
    </FormItem>
  </Form>
);
```

...

```
handleVisibleChange = (visible) => {
  this.setState({ visible });
}
```

...

```
<Popover
  content={content}
  trigger="click"
  visible={this.state.visible}
  onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}>
    <a>Click me!</a>
</Popover>
```

I thought about extending the Popover component and then overriding the onClick event of it, but I don't know how to check if the click was inside the component or it's children. Is this a valid approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when do you want the dropdown to close if not on accepting an item?

Comment: I once wanted to do a similar thing (having a popover stay up while the user clicks in a time picker), but I gave up trying to achieve it before digging into the antd click handling. If you figure it out please share. Or maybe file a feature request, but I suspect it will be (rightfully) met with "PR Welcome"...

Comment: I want to close it when the user clicks a button inside the popup after selecting an item in the Autocomplete field or when he clicks outside the popup or its content. The problem is that the Popover component considers the Autocomplete list outside of the Popover content.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue, at least for antd v4

This works as expected, popup does not close when selected from the list:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Popover, Button, AutoComplete } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";

const mockVal = (str, repeat = 1) => ({
  value: str.repeat(repeat)
});

const Complete = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const onSearch = (searchText) => {
    setOptions(
      !searchText
        ? []
        : Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => mockVal(searchText, i))
    );
  };

  const onSelect = (data) => {
    console.log("onSelect", data);
  };

  return (
    <AutoComplete
      options={options}
      style={{
        width: 200
      }}
      onSelect={onSelect}
      onSearch={onSearch}
      placeholder="input here"
    />
  );
};

const content = (
  <div>
    <Complete />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Popover content={content} title="Title" trigger="click">
      <Button>Click me</Button>
    </Popover>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```